# Javascript Works without Class Declaration

Tags: javascript

The alert works in the following code if I remove the class declaration. I feel it should work with or without it. What am I missing?

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor MyClass() {
    let x = 0;
  }
}
alert("hi");
```

Comment: _"Uncaught SyntaxError: Classes may not have a field named 'constructor'"_

Comment: If you take the habit of checking the console for errors, you'll avoid to ask syntax-error questions.

Comment: I am just making a text file and then opening it in Chrome. Is there a console available in that context?

Comment: Yes, to answer my own question, I later discovered there IS a script console available in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the name `MyClass` in the constructor.
You can refer to the official [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor () {
    let x = 0;
  }
}
alert("hi");
```

Comment: This is what I get for programming in C# and then switching over. I don't do JS much and it's been awhile. And I did check the documentation, but my eye just wasn't catching the problem. I knew it was something simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the class name from where you declare the constructor.

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    let x = 0;
  }
}
alert("hi");
```